# How to uninstall a theme without knowing its name?

Tags: compiz, themes, gtk, system, inkscape

I'm new here so I'll try to make this concise.

I recently installed a dark theme for inkscape and just realized it applied to my whole ubuntu system.  Unfortunately, I don't recall the name (stupidly, I wasn't paying much attention to what I was doing) and it has made some app settings unusable.

I definitely used the terminal to install some parts of this dark theme if that helps.

For example here is what inkscape's preferences window looks like.

[image]
Kind of unreadable..

And here is what ActionAz looks like.

[image]

there is no `.themes` directory in `~/` (pressed Ctrl+H to see hidden files)

and there is no `/theme` directory in `/usr/share/inkscape`.

I guess whatever I installed went somewhere else and is affecting my whole opperating system.  I've tried googling, messing around in system settings, and even looking around through unity tweak tool. Any Idea how to remove it or just reset the operating system to default?

As I said I'm new and have been messing around with stuff. I had installed `compizconfig-settings-manager` recently and wanted to mention it because it could have something to do with this issue. I have since uninstalled it hoping to solve this without any luck.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to war1oc for helping to solve this issue. As suggested [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/), these two commands reset unity and got rid of the problem:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Comment: Please submit the the edited portion as an answer and select it as the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to war1oc for helping to solve this issue. As suggested [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/), these two commands reset unity and got rid of the problem:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Answer (score 1):

you can install Unity Tweak Tools and then change the theme from there.

Comment: Using the unity tweak tool only changes some of the theme as seen here. http://imgur.com/5PIN2eZ  it only changes the top menu and leaves the rest of the window too dark to read.

Comment: high contrast looks the best, http://imgur.com/KO26HLT , but still the menu becomes too unreadable.  http://imgur.com/hHX2cNp  the program is supposed to look like this by default. http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CkcOqI_hSBU/TyyDmH7MCjI/AAAAAAAAAT0/blO_wvP5Qtk/s1600/Actionaz.png

Comment: try this

`unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`

Comment: if it doesn't work try this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/